# Cant login, Password MUST be reset error, after reset

Tags: login, email, password, reset

I recently forgot login to my wordpress, I changed password in mysql to md5 and can now login... But when i do i get:

"Please enter your username or email address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email. Your password must be reset. Please submit this form to reset it."

and the Problem is my server cant send emails.... so now what are my options ?

Edit: I thought i made it clear that i did manually what that script does below. If i didn't well now you know.

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole article on this in the Codex: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

I'm partial to the Emergency Password Script, but the FTP method is probably also equally as easy. Upload the following as a file to your server. Visit its URL and follow the prompts. Immediately delete the file from your server.

```
<?php
/*
    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
        it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
        the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
        (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
        but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
        MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
        GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
        along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
        Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

require './wp-blog-header.php';

function meh() {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $_POST['update'] ) ) {
        $user_login = ( empty( $_POST['e-name'] ) ? '' : sanitize_user( $_POST['e-name'] ) );
        $user_pass  = ( empty( $_POST[ 'e-pass' ] ) ? '' : $_POST['e-pass'] );
        $answer = ( empty( $user_login ) ? '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>The user name field is empty.</strong></p></div>' : '' );
        $answer .= ( empty( $user_pass ) ? '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>The password field is empty.</strong></p></div>' : '' );
        if ( $user_login != $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_login FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID = '1' LIMIT 1" ) ) {
            $answer .="<div id='message' class='updated fade'><p><strong>That is not the correct administrator username.</strong></p></div>";
        }
        if ( empty( $answer ) ) {
            $wpdb->query( "UPDATE $wpdb->users SET user_pass = MD5('$user_pass'), user_activation_key = '' WHERE user_login = '$user_login'" );
            $plaintext_pass = $user_pass;
            $message = __( 'Someone, hopefully you, has reset the Administrator password for your WordPress blog. Details follow:' ). "\r\n";
            $message  .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf( __( 'Password: %s' ), $plaintext_pass ) . "\r\n";
            @wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), sprintf( __( '[%s] Your WordPress administrator password has been changed!' ), get_option( 'blogname' ) ), $message );
            $answer="<div id='message' class='updated fade'><p><strong>Your password has been successfully changed</strong></p><p><strong>An e-mail with this information has been dispatched to the WordPress blog administrator</strong></p><p><strong>You should now delete this file off your server. DO NOT LEAVE IT UP FOR SOMEONE ELSE TO FIND!</strong></p></div>";
        }
    }

    return empty( $answer ) ? false : $answer;
}

$answer = meh();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>WordPress Emergency PassWord Reset</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo( 'html_type' ); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>/wp-admin/wp-admin.css?version=<?php bloginfo( 'version' ); ?>" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <h2>WordPress Emergency PassWord Reset</h2>
            <p><strong>Your use of this script is at your sole risk. All code is provided "as -is", without any warranty, whether express or implied, of its accuracy, completeness. Further, I shall not be liable for any damages you may sustain by using this script, whether direct, indirect, special, incidental or consequential.</strong></p>
            <p>This script is intended to be used as <strong>a last resort</strong> by WordPress administrators that are unable to access the database.
                Usage of this script requires that you know the Administrator's user name for the WordPress install. (For most installs, that is going to be "admin" without the quotes.)</p>
            <?php
            echo $answer;
            ?>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Options" /></p>

            <fieldset class="options">
                <legend>WordPress Administrator</legend>
                <label><?php _e( 'Enter Username:' ) ?><br />
                    <input type="text" name="e-name" id="e-name" class="input" value="<?php echo attribute_escape( stripslashes( $_POST['e-name'] ) ); ?>" size="20" tabindex="10" /></label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="options">
                    <legend>Password</legend>
                    <label><?php _e( 'Enter New Password:' ) ?><br />
                    <input type="text" name="e-pass" id="e-pass" class="input" value="<?php echo attribute_escape( stripslashes( $_POST['e-pass'] ) ); ?>" size="25" tabindex="20" /></label>
                </fieldset>

                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Options" /></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you post that didnt you read?
I did exactly what that script did. And the error i mentioned was nothing like what you would see if this was the problem, i wouldn't be here for such a simple problem, you just jumped to conclusions, but i tried hard to make it clear so this didnt happen.

Comment: No need to be nasty. You have no idea how many times people come on here asking questions that are answered simply in the Codex. You did *not* mention you used this particular script, so that was never clear. I simply forgot the script required `mail()`... sue me. And in any case, you could try the FTP method mentioned in Codex as that should not require any `mail()` functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Found conflicting plugin called login-secutiry-solutions, removed it and now im in, thanks for any assistance.